# Java 'constructor in class cannot be applied to given types' 'required: no arguments found: String'

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors

I'm working on an assignment where I have to create a linked list from scratch and have come across an error when compiling that the "constructor Node in class Node cannot be applied to given types;"

This is what I'm trying, the error says:

required: no arguments
found: string

Yet I cannot see where I am going wrong as my constructor for Node requires a string?

```
public class Node {
    String data;
    Node next;

    public void Node(String x) {
        data = x;
        next = null;
    }
}



public class stringList {
    private Node head;
    private int count;

    public void stringList() {
        head = null;
        count = null;
    }

    public void add(String x) {
        Node temp = new Node(x);
    }
```

[This is a screenshot of the error the compiler is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h2LI.jpg)

Comment: A constructor does not have a return. `public void Node(String x)` is a method; I think you meant `public Node(String x)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
public void Node(String x) {
    data = x;
    next = null;
}
```

should be:

```
   public Node(String x) {
        data = x;
        next = null;
    }
```

Currently you have a *default* constructor (taking no arguments), which is implicitly defined in the absence of any explicit constructors.

Comment: aren't those two snippets identical ?

Comment: What's the difference? I think your first code should be `public void Node...`

Answer (score 4):

Constructors **don't have a return type**. What you have now **is a method named** `Node`, which **returns nothing**.To fix, replace this

```
public void Node(String x){
```

with

```
public Node(String x){
```

Comment: nice catch, did not found it haha